# C Program: how can result of 1st few lines of code change based on what happens much later in program?

Tags: c, oracle-call-interface

I'm programming some C code using gcc -std=C89 switch on a Linux box. This C code communicates with an Oracle database using OCI drivers called by [OCILIB](http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/orclib/OCILIB%20Guides/ocilib-3.5.0-user-guide.pdf) libraries. After downloading the necessary data from the database, the C program calls a C function (my_function) that performs a lot of complex math. The program flow looks like:

```
int main (void) {
    OCI_Connection *cn; 
    OCI_Statement  *st;
    OCI_Resultset  *rs; 
    ...
    /* FIRST CALL TO DB */
    OCI_Initialize(NULL, NULL, OCI_ENV_DEFAULT);
    cn = OCI_ConnectionCreate(...);
    st = OCI_StatementCreate(cn);
    OCI_Prepare(st, ...);
    OCI_Bindxxx(st, ...);
    OCI_Execute(st);

    printf(...); /* verify data retrieved from database is correct */

    /* SECOND CALL TO DB */
    OCI_Prepare(st, ...); /* different prepare stmt than above */
    OCI_Bindxxx(st, ...);
    OCI_Execute(st, ...);

    printf(...); /* verify data retrieved from database is correct */

    /* THIRD CALL TO DB */
    OCI_SetFetchSize(st, 200);
    OCI_Prepare(st, ...);
    OCI_Bindxxx(st, ...);
    OCI_Execute(st);
    rs = OCI_GetResultset(st);
    ...
    printf(...); /* verify data retrieved from database is correct */

    OCI_Cleanup();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    my_function(...);
}
```

If I run the program as shown, the `printf` statements all display the correct data has been downloaded from the database into the C program. However, `my_function` has not executed.

If I then move the `return EXIT_SUCCESS` line of code from before `my_function()` to AFTER `my_function()`, re-compile the code and run it, the `printf` statements show that the data from the 1st call to the database is saved correctly in the C program, but the 2nd call's data is incorrect, and the `printf` statement from the 3rd call appears not to have done anything.

There are no errors or warnings reported at compile and run time.

I'm not that experienced in C (or OCILIB), but for those who are, is there a logical explanation how the placement of `return EXIT_SUCCESS` in the code can interact with code located much before it, to cause this?

In my simple mind, I think of the code as executing one line at a time, so if the code works to line 123 (for example), a change to the code at line 456 shouldn't effect the results up to line 123 (e.g. when comparing before-versus-after the change to line 456). Perhaps Am I missing something?

Comment: This sounds like some seriously buggy code that might have worked by slight coincidence beforehand. I suggest running this under Valgrind to try to catch some memory errors.

Comment: Thanks for the commend sarnold. Is it possible in C, to your knowledge , for memory leakage to occur related to `my_function` before that function is executed (for example, at compile time, or while the program is executing but before the function is called)? Otherwise, I'm not seeing a connection, at least in theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility is that your code is relying on the value of uninitialized variables, and that by adding the `return` before calling `myfunction()` you are changing the way the compiler lays out variables in memory.

For example, an optimizing compiler might notice that the call to `myfunction()` is unreachable because of the `return`, thus it might be able to avoid setting aside space for a temporary variable it might otherwise need for the `myfunction()` call.

Make sure your compiler is set to warn about use of uninitialized variables.

Comment: Selecting this as the answer because I did see some issues with the program execution related to uninitialized variables after reading this post. Another issue I had was I forget that computer automatically adds a null (termination) character to a character string array, which caused some problems.

Answer (score 1):

Rewritten answer:

If your code is behaving as differently as you describe, it suggests that the version with the `return` before your call doesn't include your function in its executable image (the unused code is optimized out), which changes the memory layout.  This then might be affecting your code if you have serious memory management issues.

Did you try reprinting the first data after the second lot of database activity, to ensure that you still had the information you thought you had read successfully?  Was your printing of the information retrieved thorough and complete?

Comment: .. keep reading the problem description. When it is in the correct location, the earlier code doesn't execute well. (Which screams to me that there are gigantic memory handling flaws.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your `printf` statements don't end in newlines; in this case, the output isn't flushed until the `main` ends.  This allows for `my_function` to corrupt `stdout` in the meantime.  Use newlines or `fflush` and I'll bet this apparently anomalous behavior will cease.

Comment: Thanks Matt, you're right my `printf` did not end in newlines. By newlines I think you mean `\n`, such as in `printf("my text \n");`, is that right? When I add `\n` to all my printf statements, and compile, nothing changes (I get same results). If I comment out all the printf statements, I still get same result. If I put an `fflush( stdout );` after each printf section I still get same results. Good idea though.

Comment: @ggkmath Yes, `\n` is what I meant.  Mysterious!  Please update when you figure it out.